# Как из JSON сделать список объектов?

Tags: python, json

Есть вот такой JSON, который возвращает нам сайт:

```
[{
"duration":"06:25:15.000",
"method":"com.nexage.tests.pss.PSSVerifyThatMMExchangeAdSourceCanBeUpdatedWithAllowBiddersAndBidderGroupsBySellerAdmin#xTest",
"name":"KS-4632 PSS verify that MM Exchange ad source can be updated with allow bidders and bidder groups by Seller admin",
"startTime":"2016-10-13 04:39:56.0",
"endTime":"2016-10-13 11:05:11.0",
"status":"PASSED"
},
{
"duration":"04:56:37.000",
"method":"com.nexage.tests.genevareporting.VerifyThatSellerRevenueReportCanBeDrilledDownBySellerUser#xTest",
"name":"KS-573 Verify that Seller Revenue report can be drilled down by Seller User",
"startTime":"2016-10-13 04:19:39.0",
"endTime":"2016-10-13 09:16:16.0",
"status":"PASSED"
}]
```

И есть класс:

```
class TestModel:
    def __init__(self, duration, method, name, start_time, end_time, status):
        self.duration = duration
        self.method = method
        self.name = name
        self.start_tame = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time
        self.status = status
```

Как из такого JSON, который возвращает сайт, сделать список объектов этого класса?

Answer (score 1):

Если немного поменять объявление класса, чтоб сделать имена аргументов как в json

```
class TestModel:
    def __init__(self, duration, method, name, startTime, endTime, status):
        self.duration = duration
        self.method = method
        self.name = name
        self.start_time = startTime
        self.end_time = endTime
        self.status = status
```

то совсем просто

```
import json
objlist = json.loads(your_json_str)
[TestModel(**x) for x in objlist]
# [<__main__.TestModel object at 0x02E7A530>, <__main__.TestModel object at 0x02E7A510>]
```